# How to re-render the component in react if useState does not change or hold the last value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

- I have a useState
  `const [selectFolderId, useSelectFolderId] = React.useState(documentStore.id)`
- Im reading documentStore.id from redux store, but sometimes when im changing the URL and change the document Store, my selectFolderId, always hold the last value, and does not update with the new value from DocumentStore.
  I did a useEffect passing props such as the URL or the documentStore to update the state but I'm not getting results from this.

  `useEffect(()=>{ setFolderId(documentStore.id) }, [url, documentStore])`

There is a way to always reset the value and re-render the component.
I guess react is always holding the same data from the cache, and does not update the UI, maybe does not know my documentStore.id has other value, then I don't have the data in the folderId that I would need.

How can I force my useStates to update their values in every change not just with the UseEffect, because is not changing the values, the last value of useState is pasted

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

You need to add  `documentStore.id` to your `useeffect`

```
 useEffect(()=>{ setFolderId(documentStore.id) }, [url, documentStore.id])
```

Comment: I did it does not work, I need to find one way to reset the state when the URL changes

Comment: @JavierBurgos So in the component where you land after the URL redirection you can try dispatching the action to update the state variable value in your redux state